# XS:Selector and XPath expressions

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

I was wondering what are the allowed XPath expressions when using the `xs:selector` element.
I tried to use this expression `x/y[1]` to select the first y of the x element.

I had compilation error that the expression is an invalid XPath for the selector or field.

What are the alternative for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm affraid you can use only some reduced set of XPath in XSD selector. Unfortunately tests are not allowed. Nice site about that is http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/schema/ch09_02.htm (look at chapter 9.2.5 Permitted XPath Expressions).